# Tag synonyms: voting -> elections

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Should we make [voting](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting) a synonym of [elections](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elections) ?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Agreed, good idea.